# Android:inserting array lists in database

Tags: android, database

I am making an android app in which i need to  insert the values in to database. I am getting json array as response from server side i have parsed it and stored them into array lists now i need to store these arrays in database so that i can access these values from database in another activity.

How can I accomplish this?

Can anyone help me over this?
Following is the response that i am getting from server:

```
         11-02 16:51:21.680: INFO/System.out(17786): response is  {"data":[{"resources":[{"width":"320","type":"image_png","id":"addspacewithadd","data":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAUAAAAA0CAYAAAGMU9FfAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJ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
```

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Search for *foreign key*. That's the typical way and technique. Otherwise show us your JSON and your idea of the database layout and we'll help you.

Comment: I have posted my json Can you tell me now

Answer (score 0):

My Suggtion would be if you are not using this data beyond the current instance of app (After reopening the app), then you should use intent to pass the data to other activity.

Comment: No it is my requirement as i get dynamic content and i have to up[date database each time the app goes online and then access data from database.

Comment: DB access sample is here..http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/